# SQL - Creating UTC Timestamp from separate date/time/timezone information

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I'm working with BigQuery and have a table that looks like:

| YEAR | MONTH | DAY | timezone | local time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | 6 | 24 | America/Los Angeles | 1930 |

Where local time is given by hhmm. I'm wondering if I can format this information into a timestamp column in SQL that yields time in UTC.

I know I can use `TO_TIMESTAMP` but that would involve concatenating all these columns as strings first. Is there any better way to do this? If I were to concatenate, I'm not sure how I would use timezone and then back out UTC.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
    SELECT 2015 year, 6 month, 24 day, 'America/Los_Angeles' timezone, 1930 local_time UNION ALL
    SELECT 2015 year, 6 month, 24 day, 'America/Los_Angeles' timezone, 2400 local_time
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(
         UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(DATE(year, month, day), timezone)) 
         + DIV(local_time, 100) * 3600 + MOD(local_time, 100) * 60
       ) utc
  FROM sample_table;
```

- Since `TIME(24, 0, 0)` is not a valid time format, the query converts datetime into unix seconds and get back to UTC with the time calculation in seconds.

  > Input calculates to invalid time: 24:00:00

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for this. As a follow-up, I'm getting an error: 

"Input calculates to invalid datetime: 2015-04-05 0024:00:00"

Realized that in my data, there is local time 2400 I think that is causing the problem. Is there a way to set this to 0 and then add a day (provided that there are days left in the month? I'm new to SQL and am having trouble learning these time manipulations.

EDIT: Sorry, deleted my old comment and re-commented

Comment: @JustinYoung, would you check that again if it works for your dataset ?